# Elastic search DSL query to match the log message with starting and ending text

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl, querydsl

The log messages are like below

```
The application node ABC is down
The application node BCD is down
The application node XXX  is down
```

I have written the following query but  it is not working

```
"query": {
   "must": {
          "match": {
               "log_message": {
                    "query": "The application node /[A-Z]*/ is down"
               }
          }
   }
   "filter":{
           "term": {
                "application": "XYZ"
            }
    }
}
```

How to write a DSL query to match these messages along with filter on application name.

Answer (score 0):

The first point, as you have not given index mapping considering `log_message` is defined as `text` type field without any analyzer. So it will consider default `standard` analyzer for `log_message` field.

Here, your regex pattern `/[A-Z]*/` will not work as `standard` analyzer convert all tokens into `lowercase` while indexing. You can read about standard analyzer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#_definition_4). You can replace your pattern like `/[a-z]*/

Second Point, `match` query not support regex pattern. You can use `query_string` type of query of Elasticsearch as shown below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "log_message",
            "query": "The application node /[a-z]*/ is down",
            "default_operator": "AND"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "application": "XYZ"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

> Regex query will impact your search performance so used with caution.

**Best Solution:**

If your use case to match the query on node name and application name with status of node like running or down then you can get this information from message field using  [grok pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html) with [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) and stored as separate value and use it to query.

Below is sample grok pattern for your log message (you can modified based on your various log pattern):

```
The application node %{WORD:node_name} is %{WORD:node_status}
```

Above, grok pattern will give below result:

```json
{
  "node_name": "ABC",
  "node_status": "down"
}
```

Sample Ingest Pipeline:

```json
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "log_message",
        "patterns": [
          "The application node %{WORD:node_name} is %{WORD:node_status}"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use pipeline like below while indexing document:

```json
POST index_name/_doc?pipeline=my-pipeline
{
  "log_message":"The application node XXX is down"
}
```

Output Document:

```json
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index_name",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "bZuMkoABMUDAwut6pbnf",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "node_status" : "down",
          "node_name" : "XXX",
          "log_message" : "The application node XXX is down"
        }
      }
    ]
```

You can use below query to get data for specific node which is down:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "node_name": "XXX"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "node_status": "down"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "application": "XYZ"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```